# Error installing apps and extensions from Chrome Web Store

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

Trying to install an App or Extension in Chrome Web Store fails.

[image: Console Message is this]

I don't "cancel the install". It says: "checking.." (grey) and then there is the blue install button again. No app or extension installed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I kept getting stuck on "checking" while trying to install extensions.  Poking around I found the download directory was set to "F:/Driver" for some reason.  That path doesn't exist on my system.  I set it to a valid directory, and it started working.

Comment: same here, download directory wasn't accessible.

Answer (score 2):

If the web store is giving you errors, you can directly download apps/extensions by copying the app ID and going to this link:

https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx?response=redirect&x=id%3D~~~~%26uc

You will want to replace "~~~~" with the app ID.
You can find the app ID in the URL bar of the app on the Chrome Web Store.
It will look like a random string of letters between a slash and a question mark.

If you do this, it will directly download the file. 
You can go to your extensions page and drag it on and it may install.

If it still doesn't install, change the file extension to ".zip" and extract it into a new folder and delete the zip file. Then go to your Extensions page, click "Developer mode", and click "Load unpacked extension" and click the folder you extracted it into.

This is how I install things if the Chrome Web Store isn't responding.
You can also view the source code of the app like this.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore. I get a 204 No Content response when navigating to the URL with the correct app id, for example I used [this url](https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx?response=redirect&x=id%3Dfbicpmopjallgdpklipffmihodimmcbe%26uc) for [this extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/goodreads-right-click/fbicpmopjallgdpklipffmihodimmcbe?hl=en-US)

Answer (score 1):

The instructions are for Windows, but worked on my Mac as well:

[Workaround For Google Extensions Stuck In CHECKING](http://www.timeatlas.com/5_minute_tips/annoyances/google_extension_stuck_on_checking#.UNB9hMj6YzF)

> - Click the wrench icon toward the top right of your browser.
> - From the drop-down menu select, “Settings”
> - In the Search settings textbox toward the top center, type “downloads”. A Search results page shows similar to the one below.
> - Check that the Download location: folder is correct. In my case, the text box was blank.
> - Click Change… and navigate to your new folder.
> - Make sure that your entry sticks.
> - Try to install the Google Chrome extension again.

Answer (score 1):

Downloads folder - as described in other answers - did not work for me.

However disconnecting my Google account and connecting it to Chrome once again fixed an issue.

Answer (score 0):

If all else fails. don't use the Web Store install routine - do it manually.

Download the extension file from the author's website and save it to your computer. Usually this is a zip file found at GitHub. Just click the Website link in the Chrome Web Store display for the extension and follow your nose.

Unpack/zip the zip file. It will unpack into a folder. The zip may contain multiple extensions by the author - find the folder containing the files for the extension you want.

Open Chrome's Extensions page in Settings. Enable Developer Mode. Click "Load unpacked extension" button. Navigate to the folder containing the extension's file. Click OK, it will install the extension.

Answer (score 0):

How about adding any extension manually:

1. Open http://chrome-extension-downloader.com/
2. Copy and paste URL of any google extension in http://chrome-extension-downloader.com/ search bar.
3. It will download extension in ( crx ) format.
4. After downloading go to chrome settings and then click on extensions
   from settings, this is the area where extension are installed.
5. Now drag the downloaded extension (crx) to google chrome extension
   area.
6. Google chrome will give you an option. DRAG TO INSTALL
7. Drag it and enjoy